# The expression of Type <t> is not a sequence error , LinqPad

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I use Linqpad extensively for querying databases. Today I got the following error when doing a Union operation between two result sets.

> The expression of type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`3[System.Int64,System.String]]'
>   is not a sequence

Following is the sequence of steps I did.

I am using a Oracle database and added a connection in LinqPad using IQToolkit.
I have 2 Tables with almost similar structure.

```
Table1
Field1 int
Field2 long
Field3 string

Table2
Field2 long
Field3 string
```

The table2 is similar in structure to Table1 except for the 'Field1' field.
I want to join the data in two tables.

```
var firstTableData = (from data in Table1
                      select new{Field2 = data.Feild2, Field3 = data.Field3});

var secondTableData = (from data in Table2
                       select new{Field2 = data.Field2,Field3 = data.Field3});

var combined = firstTableData.Union(secondTableData);

combined.Dump();
```

At this point, Dump displays the combined Data from both tables.

Now when I use this combined data in a join with another query like

```
var newData = (from t3 in Table3
               join c1 in combined on t3.Field2 equals c1.Field2
               select {...});
```

In the above query, I am getting the issue

```
The expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`3[System.Int64,System.String]]' is not a sequence
```

I have tried calling combined.AsQueryable(), combined.AsEnumerable() and also tried 'Concat' instead of 'Union' for combined.

```
var combined = firstTableData.Concat(secondTableData);
```

Nothing seemed to work.

Am I missing anything. 
It keeps me wondering that Dump() method does not have any such complaints.
Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Stack trace :

```
 at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.ConvertToSequence(Expression expr)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.VisitSequence(Expression source)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.BindJoin(Type resultType, Expression outerSource, Expression innerSource, LambdaExpression outerKey, LambdaExpression innerKey, LambdaExpression resultSelector)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at IQToolkit.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.DbExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.VisitSequence(Expression source)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.BindJoin(Type resultType, Expression outerSource, Expression innerSource, LambdaExpression outerKey, LambdaExpression innerKey, LambdaExpression resultSelector)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at IQToolkit.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.DbExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.VisitSequence(Expression source)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.BindWhere(Type resultType, Expression source, LambdaExpression predicate)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at IQToolkit.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.DbExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.VisitSequence(Expression source)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.BindSelect(Type resultType, Expression source, LambdaExpression selector)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at IQToolkit.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.DbExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.Visit(Expression exp)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryBinder.Bind(QueryMapper mapper, Expression expression)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryMapper.Translate(Expression expression)
   at IQToolkit.Data.Common.QueryTranslator.Translate(Expression expression)
   at IQToolkit.Data.EntityProvider.GetExecutionPlan(Expression expression)
   at IQToolkit.Data.EntityProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at IQToolkit.Data.EntitySession.SessionProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at IQToolkit.Query`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
```

Thanks,
Satish

Comment: Try adding `ToList` like this: `var combined = firstTableData.Union(secondTableData).ToList();` before you use it in the 3. query

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jens. But this doesnt help. I am still getting the same error - Satish

Comment: Could you show the callstack? I find simular errors from people using [SubSonic](https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues)

Comment: You should use [`equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713644.aspx) in a LINQ join, not `=`.

Comment: @vcsjones:That was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed that.

Comment: @JensKloster : I have edited the post and provided the stack trace. Please let me know if you need any more information - Satish

Comment: @user1879001 hmm. ok - nothing in the callstack that look interresting. What does Table3 look like?

Comment: @JensKloster : Table3 contains a column which can have values from Table1's Field2 or Table2's Field2. Hence, I am combining both Table1 and Table2 so that I have all possible values that are available in Table3.

Comment: @JensKloster : Any suggestions/workarounds for this?

Comment: @user1879001 I havn't been able to find a workaround. :-(. I'm not sure it has anything to do with LinqPad.. But if it does - maybe you should contact [Joseph Albahari](http://www.linqpad.net/feedback.aspx)